# Etiquette for Merged Question: What to do with obsolete parts in answer?

Tags: support, answers, duplicate-questions, etiquette, merged-questions

Recently one of the questions to which I had [answered](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/27541/11841) got merged with another question (as it was a duplicate).

The problem is that only a part of it was duplicate. There was an original part (about why the skin temperature is lower than core temperature) which was closely related to the duplicate part. The answer I posted had answers to both parts.

Now in the merged question, the second part of the answer would be obsolete as the OP in the question (the original to which the new question was linked to as duplicate) did not ask about it.

What do I do?

Should I remove the obsolete content? Or should I edit and say this was the answer to the question before merge? Or should I do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the obsolete parts are not likely to be useful, just remove them.

If you think they may help future readers understand the problem (as presumably they did for the asker of the duplicate), then write a short introduction for it and leave it be. It is imperative that your answer *answer the question as asked* - but there's no harm in offering related information along with it.